# Cut set, confusing definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm learning Graph Theory from *Introduction to Graph Theory* by *Robin J. Wilson*.

In chapter 3 he defines *disconecting set* and gives an example as follows:

[See definition and example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoYE5.png)

Then, he defines *cutset* in terms of desconecting set, like this:

[See definition here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffuCn.png)

*When he says "in the above example" he refers to the example in the first image.

After defining cutset, he states that $ \{ e_3, e_6, e_7, e_8 \} $ is a cutset of the exemplifying graph; nonehtheless, $ \{ e_3, e_4, e_6, e_7, e_8 \} $ is also a disconnecting set, and $ \{ e_3, e_6, e_7, e_8 \}  ⊂ \{ e_3, e_4, e_6, e_7, e_8 \} $, so, according to the definition of cutset  $ \{ e_3, e_6, e_7, e_8 \} $ can't be one, contradictory.

I'm sure there's something I'm not getting from that definition ¿Could you provide me with a better defition of cutset than the one in the book, or explain to me what I seem not to be getting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A cutset is a *minimal* disconnecting set. It is not supposed to have any disconnecting subsets, so $\{e_3,e_6,e_7,e_8\}$ is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition seems to say that a cut set is a minimal disconnecting set, so the existence of a *larger* disconnecting set doesn't appear to be a problem.

Comment: Oh, ok... English isn't my native language, so the phrasing of the definition of cutset seems to be confusing me... ¿could someone be so kind and write it in a more simple manner, specially without using that "of which"?

Comment: I'd just say "a cut set is a minimal disconnecting set."